# possible variables of a method on python modules

Tags: python

I am new to python, my question is that how we can know the arguments name of a method on a module. for example, in the smpplib module page (https://github.com/podshumok/python-smpplib) i see an example code that has a line as below

```
client.bind_transceiver(system_id='login', password='secret')
```

I what to know how i can know that bind_transceiver function has system_id password (and system_type) variable.

help (smpplib.client.Client) just give me below info about bind_transceiver

> :
>    bind_transceiver(self, **args)
>    Bind as a transmitter and receiver at once

Comment: `**args` accepts arbitrary keyword parameters, there's no way to determine which will actually do anything without reading the code or the docs.

Comment: I'm sorry if this is a stupid question .if it accepts arbitrary keyword parameters can i use systemid instead of system_id

Comment: Sure! You could call`client.bind_transceiver(bananas='login')` as far as that definition is concerned, but don't expect it to do much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**tl;dr** You would have to look at the source code or documentation to find out.

**Explanation**: `bind_transmitter` uses `**args`. This allows the person calling the function to pass in any number of *keyword* arguments. For example:

```
 bind_transmitter()  # valid
 bind_transmitter(a=1, b='4')  # valid
 bind_transmitter(myarg=1, m=6, y=7, system_id='me', password='secret')  # valid
```

As such, there is no way to know which *keyword* arguments `bind_transmitter` will actually use without examining the source code or documentation.

Comment: I thought that the required variable name should be find in the module's document and i couldn't find it so i should read the module code also . thanks to all for explanation I got a lot of help

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, in Python, functions have `**kwargs` argument that means "any key - value argument is accepted".

Key-value pairs are passed as in your example:

```
client.bind_transceiver(system_id='login', password='secret')
```

The function implementation code access the key - value pairs with the dictionary `kwargs`. So the internal code would do something like:

```
def bind_transceiver(self, **kwargs):
    # Do something with system id
    print(kwargs['system_id'])
    # Do something with password
    print(kwargs['password])
```

The output of your call to this function would be

```
login
password
```

You can pass any key-value pair to the function but there are only 2 ways to understand which keyes will be actually consumed.

1. Read the function documentation
2. Read the code

The keyes that are not used will be stored anyway in the dictionary args within the scope of the function but they won't have any effect.

It is also possible that the function accepts another argument like `*args`. This, instead of a dictionary, will be read like a tuple by the function in a similar fashion but using positional numbers as keyes.